# How to check how close a number is to another number?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer, compare

I have a TEXT FILE that looks like:

```
John: 27
Micheal8483: 160
Mary Smith: 57
Adam 22: 68
Patty: 55
```

etc etc. They are usernames that is why their names contain numbers occasionally. What I want to do is check each of their numbers (the ones after the ":") and get the 3 names that have the numbers that are closest in value to a integer (specifically named targetNum). It will always be positive.

I have tried multiple things but I am new to Python and I am not really sure how to go about this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What multiple things have you tried?

Comment: checking how close 2 numbers are is usually done with subtraction.

Comment: Are the numbers unique?

Comment: @EugeneYarmash Yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the file into a list of name/number pairs. Then [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) the list by difference between a number and `targetNum`. The first three items of the list will then contain the desired names:

```
users = []

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, num = line.split(":")
        users.append((name, int(num)))

targetNum = 50
users.sort(key=lambda pair: abs(pair[1] - targetNum))
print([pair[0] for pair in users[:3]])  # ['Patty', 'Mary Smith', 'Adam 22']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some regex recipe here :

```
import re

pattern=r'(\w.+)?:\s(\d+)'
data_1=[]
targetNum = 50
with open('new_file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=re.findall(pattern,line)
        for i in data:
            data_1.append((int(i[1])-targetNum,i[0]))

print(list(map(lambda x:x[1],data_1[-3:])))
```

output:

```
['Mary Smith', 'Adam 22', 'Patty']
```